# Google ReCaptcha without PHP plugin

Tags: ajax, json, recaptcha

I understand the cross-domain error when using ajax to try to obtain information from another website but according to jQuery you should be able to use a jsonp request instead.  I am stumped on how to achieve this when trying to display recaptcha.  The issue is I am unable to use the plugin to achieve this, which would make it so much easier.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
          function showRecaptcha() {
            Recaptcha.create("// removed for example", 'captchadiv', { 
                tabindex: 1,
                theme: "red",
                callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
            });
          }

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');

  jQuery('#contact-form').submit(function(){
      var challenge = Recaptcha.get_challenge();
      var response = Recaptcha.get_response();
      var ip = "<?php print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>";
      var private = "// removed for example";

       var requestUrl = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify?privatekey=" + private + "&remoteip=" + ip + "&challenge=" + challenge + "&response=" + response;

       jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl, function(json) {
           alert("what");
       });

   })
});
</script>

<form id="">

// Form stuff

</form>
<div id="captchadiv"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="form-submit">
```

How should I call this to googles server and obtain the correct callback.  It's basically going to return a true or false.  I either get the infamous Access-Control-Allow-Login or or an error regarding plain/text.  Anyone with suggestions?

Comment: I just realized my title was incorrect.  It was suppose to be "Google Recaptcha without PHP plugin"

Answer (score 0):

1) Google does not support JSONP output. Why? Go to 2).

2) reCAPTCHA is meant to be validated on server side code. Why? Go to 3).

3) Spammers can easily bypass your client side validation code, thus rendering any CAPTCHA solution pointless.

Comment: 1.)  That is understandable.  2)  It is validated server side on their googles end, this is why they offer the validation without the plugins. I guess the only option is to allow the cross domain for google only.

Comment: For 2), this needs to be done on *your* server side as well. It's basically your server talking to Google's. The user agent (browser) should only provide the input, not the result of the reCAPTCHA check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, Invisible reCAPTCHA

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible